# Posting data to Jax-RS using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, persistence, jax-rs

I am a new to Jax-RS and I am having some problems consuming my web service from ajax. My get requests are working as should be, and now I am trying to post some data to be saved to Oracle 11g database, my ajax call is returning just error which is making it hard to debug.

here is my ajax call

```
 function save(img)   // base64 encoded string
{


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.42.179:8082/PotholeWebservice/webresources/entities.pothole/post",
    data: img,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("saved to database");
    },
    error: function(textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("error in saving to database: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

here is my jax-rs post method

```
 @POST
@Path("post")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(@PathParam("paramImg") String paramImg) {

    Date date = new Date();
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder(); // decode base64 image to byte[]
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(paramImg);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PotholeFacadeREST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Pothole entity = new Pothole(decodedBytes, date);
    super.create(entity);

}
```

super class

```
// super.create
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);

}
```

my class

```
public class Pothole implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Column(name = "IMAGE")
private byte[] image;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_Seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="IDSeq",sequenceName="ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1) 
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private BigDecimal id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PDATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date pdate;

public Pothole() {
}

public Pothole(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Pothole( byte[] image, Date pdate) {

    this.image = image;
    this.pdate = pdate;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public BigDecimal getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getPdate() {
    return pdate;
}

public void setPdate(Date pdate) {
    this.pdate = pdate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method parameter `paramImg` marked with `@PathParam("paramImg")` to be injected is an empty string because you do not have corresponding template defined in `@Path("post")` (i.e. `@Path("post\{paramImg}"`). This may be an issue.

If you want inject the request entity in your resource method, omit the annotation and JAX-RS will make sure the entity gets injected.

Turn on [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html) (to see how take a look at this [article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/)) to see what is going on the server-side. Please post the logs.

Comment: I did work this out last night, now I just need to check my constructor is correct as I am using a generated ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you still doesnt have the web service up and running, use this:

```
@GET
public String echo() {
    return "My service is working! > " + new Date().toString();
}
```

And use the web browser just to be sure that you can access it using a Get request.

If you don't receive the echo, so, there is a high chance that the service has not been published. Maybe you don't have an ApplicationRestConfig, let me give you an example:

```
/**
 * Initialize the rest resources, here you should add ALL the REST classes.
 */
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationRestConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(MyServiceRest.class, OtherRestService.class));
    }
}
```

If even after all these checks is still not working, check this tutorial > 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-and-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Comment: My service is up and running my get requests work fine. Its the post that fails. Im thinking it might be something to do with my constructor for my class and the Sequence I am using for the ID.

Comment: you should create the entities using an @Stateless (or @Stateful), did you have it? ... how looks your superclass?